# biojava Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Tags: bioinformatics, biojava

What is wrong in code?

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    ArrayList<String> fileName = new ArrayList<String> ();
    fileName.add("2M3T.fasta.txt");
    fileName.add("3LWK.fasta.txt");
    ArrayList<ProteinSequence> al = new ArrayList<ProteinSequence>();
    ArrayList<ProteinSequence> all =  new ArrayList<ProteinSequence>();
    for (String fn : fileName)
    {
    al = getProteinSequenceFromFasta(fn);
    all.add(al.get(0));
    for  (ProteinSequence s : al)
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    }
    Profile<ProteinSequence, AminoAcidCompound> profile = Alignments.getMultipleSequenceAlignment(all);
    System.out.printf("Clustalw:%n%s%n", profile);
    ConcurrencyTools.shutdown();
    }
    //for (int i=0;i<sequence.size();i++)
    //  System.out.println(sequence);


public static ArrayList<ProteinSequence> getProteinSequenceFromFasta(String file) throws Exception{

    LinkedHashMap<String, ProteinSequence> a = FastaReaderHelper.readFastaProteinSequence(new File(file));
    //sztuczne
    ArrayList<ProteinSequence> sequence =  new ArrayList<ProteinSequence>(a.values());


    return sequence;
}
```

}

GSKTGTKITFYEDKNFQGRRYDCDCDCADFHTYLSRCNSIKVEGGTWAVYERPNFAGYMYILPQGEYPEYQRWMGLNDRLSSCRAVHLPSGGQYKIQIFEKGDFSGQMYETTEDCPSIMEQFHMREIHSCKVLEGVWIFYELPNYRGRQYLLDKKEYRKPIDWGAASPAVQSFRRIVE
SMSAGPWKMVVWDEDGFQGRRHEFTAECPSVLELGFETVRSLKVLSGAWVGFEHAGFQGQQYILERGEYPSWDAWGGNTAYPAERLTSFRPAACANHRDSRLTIFEQENFLGKKGELSDDYPSLQAMGWEGNEVGSFHVHSGAWVCSQFPGYRGFQYVLECDHHSGDYKHFREWGSHAPTFQVQSIRRIQQ
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.forester.phylogeny.PhylogenyNode.addAsChild(Lorg/forester/phylogeny/PhylogenyNode;)V
    at org.forester.evoinference.distance.NeighborJoining.execute(NeighborJoining.java:127)
    at org.biojava3.alignment.GuideTree.(GuideTree.java:88)
    at org.biojava3.alignment.Alignments.getMultipleSequenceAlignment(Alignments.java:183)
    at Fasta.main(Fasta.java:42)

Comment: possible duplicate of [biojava Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24428773/biojava-exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception)

Comment: are you using your own copy of forrester or the one that comes with biojava?

Comment: I couldnt find forester.jar. Im using the one from: http://code.google.com/p/forester/downloads/list?can=2&q=forester&colspec=Filename+Summary+Uploaded+ReleaseDate+Size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using the wrong version of forester.

According to the Maven pom file, Biojava 3.08 depends on forester 1.005 while the latest version of forester on it's google code page is 1.028.

It's probably also better to get the jar from the Biojava maven repository to ensure the correct versions are used.

download the jar from this URL:

http://biojava.org/download/maven/org/forester/1.005/